# Redis - is there a way to to divide one Redis server instance into 2 subredis servers?

Tags: redis, jedis

I was wondering if there is a way to divide one Redis server into 2 different sub-servers? Specifically is there a way to have:

Sub-server1:

a  1 (a - key, 1 - value)

b  2

c  3

Sub-server2:

a  4

b  5

c  6

so that I can search for keys in one sub-server (for example use something like "GET a in Sub-server2", and get value 4)?

I am including jedis tag because the final goal is to make that work in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis already has an idea of *database*. A single Redis instance has 16  (0 to 15) separate databases.

You can use this idea of database to your idea of *sub-server*. For example, use database-1 as sub-server1, database-2 as sub-server2.

Jedis also supports database. Choose a constructor which has `database` parameter, pass the proper database value and you're done!